# LightDM and GDM login loop. Ubuntu 15.04 Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, login, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

At first the GDM worked just fine but all of a sudden I lost the ability to login. I can still get to my desktop using startx (sound doesn't seem to work when I do that but it might be a by-product of having to use root privileges to get startx to run.) There doesn't seem to be anything especially incriminating in any of the error logs or journalctl except for

```
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA systemd[1]: Starting ACPI event daemon...
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA systemd[1]: Started Run Click system-level hooks.
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA acpid[1295]: starting up with netlink and the input layer
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA acpid[1295]: 9 rules loaded
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA acpid[1295]: waiting for events: event logging is off
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA acpid[1295]: client connected from 1288[0:0]
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA acpid[1295]: 1 client rule loaded
Mai 10 03:56:38 curtis-UX301LAA systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 384 (plymouthd).
```

I know this is really vague but if someone could point me towards where to start finding potential errors I'm sure I'd be able to make progress on this.

Q:What is the best way going about debugging this?

P.S. The issue isn't with permissions and I've uninstalled-reinstalled both GDM and lightDM many times. The only thing I can think of is there is something up with my lightdm config file but all I have in there is autologin and user-session=gnome. Also there is nothing in .xsession-error. This is what makes my issue different from [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).

Updates: It seems that the sessions are getting correctly started and actually persist (at least as far as I can tell by looking at the journalctl output.) There are no errors getting returned from X but I do see dbus errors scattered a little bit everywhere.

Comment: The point of me pointing out that there was no permission issues was so that it wouldn't be marked as a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what I did to get lightdm to successfully start a session for me except maybe allowing anyone (not just consoles) to connect to the xserver. The gnome-shell desktop still doesn't appear when I login through lightdm while it does when using startx.